# What is the simplest way to calculate energy earned based on time?

Tags: algorithm

A player has 0 energy, and gains 5 every 15 minutes, but has a maximum of 100 energy.

How would I be able to both store this in a database, and then recall the data later, to figure out how much energy the player now has?

The only way that I can think of is to save both the last updated time as well as the energy level at the last update, but that feels like it is not the best way.

Are there alternatives to this that are more efficient or 'better' and feel less kludge-y?

Comment: What feels bad about it exactly? Using two integers to store two pieces of information seems clean and effective solution to me. You could get fancy with database triggers and move the logic onto db, always reading the up-to-date value in your app, but triggers are known for not-so-good performance.

Comment: You've found the simplest way. Perhaps it's not elegant, but start with simple and you can make it elegant later if there's time or a problem with simple.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I was wrong about it. I was just trusting my gut on it.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you *could* store only a single variable for this, if you wanted to. Rather than a stored charge level and a stored time, you store the time you would have had to start charging from zero to reach where you are now. You can then compare against that fictional zero moment to get your current energy at any later time;

```
chargePerSecond = 5/(15 * 60)

SetEnergy(currentEnergy) {
   pseudoChargeStart = now 
     - currentEnergy/chargePerSecond
}

GetEnergy() {
   return 
      min(100, 
         ( now - pseudoChargeStart ) 
         * chargePerSecond )
}
```

(Above assuming you're varying energy continuously for simplicity. Similar formulas can do this in a stepped fashion if needed)

I don't recommend this though. It's less obvious what this code does, and that clarity makes it easier for mistakes and bugs to creep in. Compare to the direct/basic method, which we can verify for correctness at a glance:

```
SetEnergy(currentEnergy) {
    lastSetEnergy = currentEnergy
    lastSetTime = now
}

GetEnergy() {
   return 
      min(100, lastSetEnergy
         + ( now - lastSetTime ) 
         *  chargePerSecond )
}
```

The other point to consider is how easy it is to maintain as your game changes. If the designers suddenly decide they don't want a linear charge rate anymore, but some kind of custom non-linear curve, then the one-field method gets much more complicated to work out.

And really, all it saves you is a matter of bytes per player. A typical game almost certainly has bigger fish to fry. ;)